# parameter difference between C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++

**C++**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void doSomething(int y)  
{             
    cout << y << " "<< & y << endl; 

}

int main()
{
    
    int x(0);
    cout << x << " " << & x << endl; 
    doSomething(x); 
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Python**

```py
def doSomething(y):
    
    print(y, id(y))

x = 0

print(x, id(x))

doSomething(x)
```

---

I think their code should return same result however
C ++ result is

```
0 00000016C3F5FB14

0 00000016C3F5FAF0
```

Python result is

```
0 1676853313744

0 1676853313744
```

**i don't understand why variable's address isn't changed in Python while variable's address is changed in C++**

Comment: Because in python, we pass an object reference instead of the actual object. If you change the function declaration of `doSomething` to `void doSomething(int& y) ` you will see that now you get the same result as python.

Comment: In c++, `x` is the variable declared in main, while `y` is the function input parameter variable. So, indeed, `x` and `y` actually doesn't have the same address, then `&x` and `&y` does not points to the same location.

Comment: @Sedenion No, `x` is not a global variable. It is a local variable in function `main`.

Comment: @AnoopRana you right, language abuse, my bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> i don't understand why variable's address isn't changed in Python while variable's address is changed in C++.

Because in python, we pass an **object reference** instead of the actual object.

While in your C++ program we're passing `x` **by value**. This means the function `doSomething` has a separate copy of the argument that was passed and since it has a separate copy their addresses differ as expected.

---

It is possible to make the C++ program produce the equivalent output as the python program as described below. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/bmC55WNNL)

If you change the function declaration of `doSomething` to `void doSomething(int& y)`  you will see that now you get the same result as python. In the modified program below, i've changed the parameter to be an `int&` instead of just `int`.

```
//------------------v---->pass object by reference
void doSomething(int& y)  
{             
    cout << y << " "<< & y << endl; 

}

int main()
{
    
    int x(0);
    cout << x << " " << & x << endl; 
    doSomething(x); 
    return 0;
}
```

The [output](https://onlinegdb.com/bmC55WNNL) of the above modified program is equivalent to the output produced from python:

```
0 0x7ffce169c814
0 0x7ffce169c814
```